# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I create a login layout but when i try to write this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
```

it shows me an error

```
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.look.instragramclone/com.example.look.instragramclone.Likes.LikesActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
```

i can not find the problem. i am adding relevant codes

I tried adding these library:

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

//Design support library for coordinator layout
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:2.0.2'

//Circular Image
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'

//universal image loader
implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'

login layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="55dp"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/instagram_logo"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:id="@+id/input_email"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:id="@+id/input_password"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:id="@+id/btn_Login"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_btn"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:text="No account yet? Create one"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/link_singup"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/loginRequestLoadingProgressBar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pleasr wait..."
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/loginRequestLoadingProgressBar"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/loginRequestLoadingProgressBar"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/loginRequestLoadingProgressBar"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

java:

```
private static final String TAG = "LikesActivity";

private Context mContext = LikesActivity.this;

private static final int ACTIVITY_NO = 3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    -->Note: this line shows the error

    //setupNavigationView();
}
/***BottomNavigationView setup***/

private void setupNavigationView(){

    BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNavigation(mContext,bottomNavigationViewEx);
    Menu menu = bottomNavigationViewEx.getMenu();
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(ACTIVITY_NO);
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use TextInputLayout insted of TextInputEdittext.

below code is for textinputlayout use:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
   android:id="@+id/usernameWrapper"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:hint="Email"/> 

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not treat TextInputEditText as a ViewGroup by placing a child inside in the following xml -

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:id="@+id/input_email"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText>
```

You need to use it as a view using -

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/> // close this tag here
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem apparently the style for my `InputLayout` was not configured properly I tried changing that and the error was solved and also we can use `EditText` instead of `InputEditText` inside `InputTextLayout`